# Way to share an dependency between class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I have three class needing to share a dependency. The latter is initialisated by one of them.The SettingsViewModel contains the data to initialize the dependency and it need to be deleted at the end of the activity. NetworkViewModel and TimeViewModel use it as an interface since the dependancy is an interface with the logic to handle Bluetooth.

SettingsViewModel -->(initialize) SingletonDependency.

NetworkViewModel  --> (use).

TimeViewModel     --> (use).

How can I make Hilt (or manual) injection to use the same interface? If I understand well I can't use singleton here since I need to iniatilize the dependency when the activity start.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider that your class name is SomeClass you can provide a live data of this class like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object SingeltonModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSomeClassLiveData(): MutableLiveData<SomeClass> {
        return MutableLiveData<SomeClass>()
    }
}
```

in your SettingsViewModel do this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val SomeClassLiveData: MutableLiveData<SomeClass>
) : ViewModel() {


    init{
        someClassLiveData.value = SomeClass()
    }

}
```

and in other view models you can inject this to contractors and observe it:

```
@HiltViewModel
class NetworkViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val SomeClassLiveData: MutableLiveData<SomeClass>
) : ViewModel() {


    init{
        someClassLiveData.observeForEver{
            //do what you want with value
        }
    }

}
```